# If insert into database succed echo

Tags: php, mysql

A simple register form with username and password and i want if the form succed to be inserted into the database to echo 'Account created'; but if the page is refreshed don't add again the registry.

I resolved the refresh problem with `header('Location: signup.php');` but i can't figure out how to echo if the account was inserted in database.

```
$numeocupat=mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testlog WHERE username='".$username."'"));

if($numeocupat!=0){echo 'Username already used';}

else{ $insert=mysql_query('INSERT INTO `testlog` (`username`, `password`) 

VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'")');

echo 'Account created.';

header('Location: signup.php');}
```

Comment: from your code, even if the echo happens, you are going immediately out due to the header. you should create some functions and execute things according to what happens and the results you obtain.

Comment: Did you find a tutorial somewhere that instructed you to use this code or did you do this on your own? There are too many mistakes here sadly, your redirect won't work and your code is highly prone to SQL injection.

Comment: @N.B. In my server the code works without errors but i dont know how to resolve these two problems the refresh problem and the echo in the same php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
$numeocupat=mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testlog WHERE username='".$username."'"));

if($numeocupat!=0){echo 'Username already used';}

else{ $insert=mysql_query('INSERT INTO `testlog` (`username`, `password`) 

VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'")');

echo 'Account created.';

header('Location: signup.php?created=1');}
```

and at the start of signup.php:

```
if($_GET['created'])
{
     echo 'Account created.';
}
```

Comment: I dont really know how to make this. I have 17 and i just started to use php. But @saman khademi answer works.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now how the GET thing works (:

Comment: i won't mind an upvote if you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
header( "refresh:5;url=signup.php" )
```

replace

```
header('Location: signup.php');}
```